# Парсинг сайта с добавлением в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу парсер для сайта  https://kladr-rf.ru/ 
1) нужно получить все города со всех регионов и улицы со всех городов, данные о городах и улицах спарсил 
2) далее нужно записать данные в базу(желательно из json файла) в поле адрес в порядке "Город|Улица|дом" а также в поле region_id  записывать id каждого региона в котором есть эти города.  Не могу разобраться как это сделать.  Есть ли какие то мысли как это все можно организовать? Ниже код который парсит города и улицы.

```
$url = 'https://kladr-rf.ru/';
$file = file_get_contents($url);

for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {  
  $url_region = 'https://kladr-rf.ru/0'.$i.'/000/'; 
  $region_files = file_get_contents($url_region);
  $document = phpQuery::newDocument($region_files);
  $needle = "Город";
  $region_find = $document->find('.span4 a:contains("'.$needle.'")')->text();
  $region_next = $document->find('.span4 a:contains("'.$needle.'")')->next()->attr('href');

  $array_cities[] = $region_find;
  for($j = 1; $j < 5; $j++) { 
    $url = 'https://kladr-rf.ru/0'.$i.'/000/00'.$j.'/000/';
    $files = file_get_contents($url);
    $document = phpQuery::newDocument($files);
    $street_find = $document->find('.span4')->text();
    $array_streets[] = $street_find; 

  }

}


$result_city = array_unique($array_cities);
$result_streets = array_unique($array_streets);
//print_r($result_city);
print_r($result_streets);

$file = file_get_contents('data.json');
$array_kldr = json_decode($file,TRUE);
unset($file);
$array_kldr = [
'city'=>$result_city,
'streets'=>$result_streets,
];

file_put_contents('data.json',json_encode($array_kldr));
unset($array_kldr);
```

Comment: Зачем вам кодировать в json, чтобы потом тут же декодировать из него?

Comment: Читая описание вопроса, когда наткнулся на "ай ди" сразу вспомнил фразу из мема - "эй Свинтура!" ахахах

Comment: в чем конкретно проблема? и опишите структуру массива

Comment: @Anton Khomutenko ну если конкретнее то,  допустим когда я спарсил все данные как добавлять их в массив так чтобы это было в таком формате 
[
 [
  'city_name'=>'Название города',
  'streets'=>[
   [
    'streets_name'=>'Название улицы',
    'params'=>[
     
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
]